# Sorting the string with comma separated numbers and assign sequence

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-component, mule4

I have a string value coming as "AH-0000006620, AH-0000006619, AH-0000006621", where I need to Remove the Prefix and the remaining numbers "0000006620, 0000006619, 0000006621" to be sorted in Ascending order and I want to store the sequence number for each of them like
for 0000006619 value to be 1
for 0000006620 value to be 2
for 0000006621 value to be 3

So that when I send the info to target system, while iterating the array, for the first element if it is 0000006620 then I will pass the value as 2 for the other sequence tag.
Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Please add the expected output for that input.

Comment: The expected output is { "AH-0000006619" : 0, "AH-0000006620" : 1, "AH-0000006621" : 2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak this though this should serve as a good starting point to what you are looking for:

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
var inp = "AH-0000006620,AH-0000006619,AH-0000006621"
---
{((inp replace"AH-" with "") splitBy "," map ($ replace /^0+/ with "") orderBy $ map {
     (leftPad($ as String,10,0)) : ($$)
})}
```

You can do it this way as well.

```
{((inp replace"AH-" with "") splitBy ","  orderBy $ as Number map {
     ($) : ($$)
})}
```

```
**Output**
```

[
{
"0000006619": 0
},
{
"0000006620": 1
},
{
"0000006621": 2
}
]

Comment: You don't need to do the map and replace. You can just do `splitBy "," orderBy $ as Number`. And you can also avoid `leftPad` too like this.

Comment: The above output I want to store in a key value format and later when iterating the array and when my index will be 0000006619, I want to find the value of it by matching with the key 0000006619.

Comment: What would be the value that you would like to store against the key ? Currently the value that you would get is the index of the key in output after that has been sorted.

Comment: @SalimKhan, I want the output to be as { "0000006619": 0 ,  "0000006620": 1 , "0000006621": 2 } with out the Array.